# MS Access 2003/2007 VBA - How can I take a date field from a recordset and string the dd-MMM-yyyy format?

Tags: ms-access, vba, automation, powerpoint, office-automation

i have some VB that uses DAO to grab some data, one field being a date field (as in date of a transaction). its not date/time, just simply date like dd/mm/yyyy.

so on an access form i know how to do this, but right now i am working on some excel/ppt automation. i use something like this simple example DAO sql string, openrecordset to get the data.

So lets say the data in question is just rs!Date.

I move it to powerpoint like so:

```
Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes("S1_Date")
Set oTextRange = oShape.textFrame.TextRange

     oTextRange.Text = rs!Date
```

now i am leaving out all kinds of stuff, but this is the part that transfers this date that I already have in the recordset, on to the ppt pres just fine, only in this format

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

and i would really just like to know how to simply get this

```
"dd-MMM-yyyy"
```

as my desired output string.

thanks
justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
oTextRange.Text = Format(rs![Date], "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

I enclosed the field name in square brackets because Date is a reserved word.  But I don't think it should make any difference in this case.  Nevertheless, try to avoid reserved words for your field, table, and other object names.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Format` function.

Try this in the debug window `Msgbox Format (Now(), "dd-MMM'YYYY")`.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is the first time I am ever answering my own question, so if i am not supposed to do this....apologies.

i figure i would show what I did incase anyone else wants to know

```
Set oShape = oSlide.Shapes("S1_Date")
Set oTextRange = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange

     oTextRange.Text = Format(rs!Date, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

and that was it. it was easy enough for me to figure out myself.

EDIT: Oops....sorry did not have other answers when i posted this!

Comment: AFAIK, it's perfectly legal to answer your own question.  Folks might complain if you were posting questions with the apparent intent of answering them immediately to inflate your point total.  Clearly that was not the case.